# Reserialize AFHTTPRequestOperationManager operationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afoauth2client

I may be going about this the wrong way, but I am trying to add a mechanism to an SDK that I am developing around an API using AFNetworking. The sdk connects to the remote API and authenticates using OAuth2. I am implementing the AFOAuth2Manager and things are working however...

I want to allow the user to authenticate to the OAuth endpoint at application start. While the authentication block is bing called all other requests in the app are being queued because I have `operationQueue` suspended on the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. Once the auth returns successful, update the request serializer header fields and un suspend the `operationQueue`. At this point, the `operationQueue` is already filled with requests that have been serialized with the wrong token. Is there a way I can re-serialize the items in the operationQueue, or can I set the authorization header when the queue attempts to do the work instead of when the work is added to the queue?